# VisualStudioCode does not give output

Tags: python, html, css, visual-studio-code

I am using Windows 10 Home.I have Python 3.9.1 and Visual Studio Code.I am studying to Flask in Visual Studio Code. I just want to run this code:

```
from flask import Flask

app =Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Home Page"

index()
```

After I open the terminal and I write 'python hello.py(hello is my files name)'.But It doesn'work.Nothing happens when I press ent, we just skip a line.

What should I do?

Comment: btw it is  ***Windows 10 Home*** and not  ***Microsoft 10 Home***

Comment: ***Mindows*** ‼⁉

Comment: sorry you are right . my fault @ManasKhandelwal

Comment: Have you installed flask.

Comment: I corrected the spelling mistake @ManasKhandelwal

Comment: Yes I did @ManasKhandelwal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Home Page"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

when you run this script in terminal you will see some information when it starts development server, e.g.

```
 * Serving Flask app "hello" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Mar/2021 13:30:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Mar/2021 13:30:48] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Now, open your browser and go to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

Note, there are different ways to structure and run your flask app, please refer to docs or tutorial..

Comment: Thank you so much @buran I am very greatful for your help

Comment: what do you mean it is not working? You realize you are building a web app, right? You will see the result in web browser. I advise you to find a tutorial and follow it.

Comment: No, it works now. I just asked why the method I used didn't work. But I saw the note you added later, so I changed my comment.